# Definition of $O (.) $ notation

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

The book I am currently reading defined the big oh operator as the following: A function $ g (x) $ said to be $ O (h (x)) $ as $ x \to l $ if $\lim \sup_{x \to l} |g (x)/h (x)| < \infty $. What I don't get about this definition is the supremum.

First of all, using the definiton of limit supremum, can the above statement be interpreted as $\lim_{x \to l} \sup_{ |l - k| < x}  |g (k)/h (k)| < \infty$ , meaning that we are taking the limit of the supremums of the $ g / h $ division on decreasing intervals around $ l $?

Secondly, why do we need the supremum? Why a straightforward limit like $\lim_{x \to l} |g (x)/h (x)| < \infty $ is not enough?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Having a limit in the definition assumes such a thing exists. lim sup is always defined.

Comment: What about if somewhere in the proximity of $ l $ it is $ h (x)=0$? How can be lim sup defined then?

Comment: @UfukCanBiçici it wouldn't necessarily be defined there - in that case (unless $g(x)$ were also in the proximity of 0 there) the lim sup would be $\infty$

Comment: Take for example the function $f(x) = |x|^k$. Then certainly $f(x) = O(x^k)$ as $x \to 0$, but $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{|x|^k}{x^k} = 1\text{ and}\\\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{|x|^k}{x^k}=-1$$so the limit is not defined for this function. However, the $\limsup$ is defined and is $1$.

Comment: IMHO, it is simpler to say that $|f(x)|\le C |h(x)|$ in a neighborhood of $l$, for some constant $C>0$. This is equivalent to the definition given in the book, but (IMHO again) easier to visualize.

Comment: I see. Then is my definition for the limsup correct in the first question? As $ x $ approaches to $ l $ from both sides we take the limit of the supremums of the decreasing interval around $ l $?

Comment: @UfukCanBiçici You should replace your $\sup_{|l-k|<x}$ by $\sup_{|l-k| < |x-l|}$.